# Dynamic column resize with text overflow

Tags: css

I have a table with one resizable column. on initial load I set the following CSS, and set the min width to 150px. However some cell-text is eclipsed due to 150px width

```
.table__name-cell {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Upon resizing the column I want the text to dynamically adjust and fill the cell width. As depicted in this gif below I am not able to achieve that effect. As you see the second row last word (Financials), doesn't come up completely, also the 3rd row last word (Corporation).

[image]

How can I fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try taking out the width:150px? since you already have the min-width:150px

Comment: That would set the width to px that can contain the longest string in the column. I don't want that. I want an initial width of 150px and then allow the user to dynamically increase the width if they want to...

Comment: could you provide an alternate solution. This answer doesn't work for my usecase